# Erro durante DELETE: You can't specify target table '...' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando deletar dados (onde o estoque for igual a zero e valor do desconto for menor do que a media total do valor do desconto) com essa query:

`DELETE FROM veiculo WHERE estoquetotal = 0 AND valordesconto < (SELECT AVG(valordesconto) FROM veiculo);`

Porém, é retornado pra mim `"You can't specify target table 'veiculo' for update in FROM clause"`.

Já pesquisei por uma solução aqui, mas não estou conseguindo aplicar nenhuma delas em minha query (sou novato em banco de dados MySQL). Das respostas que eu pesquisei, elas tinham a ver com `JOIN`. 
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já li e respondi isso em algum lugar, que eu saiba o mysql não aceita alteração de dados com consulta na mesma tabela.

então tente alterar a sua consulta para que user uma variavel no lugar de fazer

```
(SELECT AVG(valordesconto) FROM veiculo);
```

armazene o valor em uma [variável](https://imasters.com.br/artigo/3071/mysql/usando-variaveis-no-mysql?trace=1519021197&source=single) e depois use na consulta.

```
@valordesconto =  (SELECT AVG(valordesconto) FROM veiculo);

DELETE FROM veiculo WHERE estoquetotal = 0 AND valordesconto < @valordesconto ;
```